# Add new row on load programmatically on material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

The goal would be to trigger the Add row function which show a new row form with inputs and all given a certain condition. Is this possible at all ? How would I go about achieving this ?

An example of the behavior I want to achieve can be found in the documentation under "Editable Example - Editable Preview" : https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable .

The only difference is that I would not need to click on the button to trigger the add new row function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation and didn't see an API reference (what internal methods can be called) so I am not sure the correct function to call, but I am sure this can be done with forwardRefs.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const tableRef = React.createRef();

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        tableRef.current.addNewRow(); // addNewRow probably not the name of the function
    }

<MaterialTable
  title="Editable Preview"
  tableRef={tableRef} // you need this
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  editable={{
    onRowAdd: newData =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setData([...data, newData]);
          
          resolve();
        }, 1000)
      }),
    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const dataUpdate = [...data];
          const index = oldData.tableData.id;
          dataUpdate[index] = newData;
          setData([...dataUpdate]);

          resolve();
        }, 1000)
      }),
    onRowDelete: oldData =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const dataDelete = [...data];
          const index = oldData.tableData.id;
          dataDelete.splice(index, 1);
          setData([...dataDelete]);
          
          resolve()
        }, 1000)
      }),
  }}
/>

    <Button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Add Row</Button>;
}
```

You can use the javascript debugger to see what methods are available on tableRef.current and find the correct "add row" function.